# WPF: Binging TextBox + Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I create window with DataGrid and TextBox:

```
    <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CRow}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="505" Margin="0,46,0,0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1152" Name="MainDataGrid" CellEditEnding="MainDataGridCellEditEnding" SelectedCellsChanged="MainDataGridSelectedCellsChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="MainDataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="CellContextMenu">
                <MenuItem Name="DataGridUndoMenuItem" Command="Undo" Header="Undo">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/Undo.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Command="Redo" Header="Redo">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/Redo.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Command="Cut" Header="Cut">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/Cut.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Command="Copy" Header="Copy">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/Copy.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Command="Paste" Header="Paste">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/Paste.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <Separator></Separator>
                <MenuItem Header="Add in Translation Database" Click="AddInTranslationDtbMenuClick"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Search in Translation Database" Click="SearchInTranslationDatabase"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="30" Binding="{Binding Path=Number, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Header="№" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="40*" Binding="{Binding Path=Tags, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Header="Tags" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Tags, Converter={StaticResource TagsToBrushConvecter}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="250*" Binding="{Binding Path=ID, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="ID">
                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CellContextMenu}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="390*" Binding="{Binding Path=OriginalText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Header="Original">
                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CellContextMenu}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="390*" Binding="{Binding Path=Translation, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Header="Translation">
                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CellContextMenu}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>



<TextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="75" Margin="1,26,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=MainDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem.Translation, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1152" Name="TranslationTextBox" TextChanged="TranslationTextBoxTextChanged" ContextMenuOpening="TranslationTextBoxContextMenuOpening">
            <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Command="Undo" Header="Undo">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Images/Undo.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Command="Redo" Header="Redo">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Images/Redo.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator/>
                    <MenuItem Command="Cut" Header="Cut">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Images/Cut.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Command="Copy" Header="Copy">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Images/Copy.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Command="Paste" Header="Paste">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Images/Paste.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator></Separator>
                    <MenuItem Command="SelectAll" Header="Select All">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Images/SelestAll.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBox.ContextMenu>
            <!--<SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
                <System:Uri>pack://application:,,,/Dictionaries/Russian.lex</System:Uri>
            </SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>-->
        </TextBox>
```

The code populates a table through ObservableCollection:

```
MainDataGrid.ItemsSource = Rows; //ObservableCollection<CRow> Rows
```

But when I change the text in the TranslationTextBox, then the DataGrid changes appear only when I start to edit the cell.
How to fix it?

CRow code:

```
public enum RowSearchMode { IgnoreCase, MatchCase, Regex }
public class CRow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string OriginalText { get; set; }
    public string Translation { get; set; }

    public CRow(int iNumber, string strID, string strOriginalText, string strTranslation)
    {
        Number = iNumber;
        ID = strID;
        OriginalText = strOriginalText;
        Translation = strTranslation;

        Tags = "";
    }

    public CRow():this(0,"","",""){}

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string strName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(strName));
        }
    }

    public bool Contrains(string strText, RowSearchMode hMode = RowSearchMode.IgnoreCase)
    {
        switch (hMode)
        {
            case RowSearchMode.MatchCase:
                return ID.Contains(strText) || OriginalText.Contains(strText) || Translation.Contains(strText);
            case RowSearchMode.IgnoreCase:
                return ID.ToLower().Contains(strText.ToLower()) || OriginalText.ToLower().Contains(strText.ToLower()) || Translation.ToLower().Contains(strText.ToLower());
            case RowSearchMode.Regex:
                return Regex.IsMatch(ID, strText) || Regex.IsMatch(OriginalText, strText) || Regex.IsMatch(Translation, strText);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Replace(string strOldText, string strNewText, RowSearchMode hMode = RowSearchMode.IgnoreCase)
    {
        switch (hMode)
        {
            case RowSearchMode.MatchCase:
                ID = ID.Replace(strOldText, strNewText);
                Translation = Translation.Replace(strOldText, strNewText);
                OriginalText = OriginalText.Replace(strOldText, strNewText);
                break;
            case RowSearchMode.IgnoreCase:
                ID = ID.Replace(strOldText, strNewText);
                Translation = Translation.Replace(strOldText, strNewText);
                OriginalText = OriginalText.Replace(strOldText, strNewText);
                break;
            case RowSearchMode.Regex:
                var hRegex = new Regex(strOldText);
                ID = hRegex.Replace(ID, strNewText);
                Translation = hRegex.Replace(Translation, strNewText);
                OriginalText = hRegex.Replace(OriginalText, strNewText);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to raise the property change for your property like below in order to let UI know it is changing.

```
private string _translation;
public string Translation 
{ 
     get
     {
          return _translation;
     } 
     set
     {
         _translation = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Translation");
     }

}
```